# Difference in price change ratio from day before in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have the following df:

```
   ID   Date            A_price B_price
    3   01/01/2013 00:00    2   5
    3   02/01/2013 00:00    3   6
    1   01/01/2013 00:00    2   4
    1   02/01/2013 00:00    5   2
    1   03/01/2013 00:00    4   4
    1   04/01/2013 00:00    8   10
    1   05/01/2013 00:00    8   2
    1   06/01/2013 00:00    2   5
    1   01/01/2013 00:00    3   6
```

I want to calculate 2 new columns: A_price_ratio_increase, B_price_ratio_increase that will calculate the price increase from yesterday for the specific ID only.
Thought about creating 2 new columns with the price of yesterday using `df.groupyby(['ID','DATE'])['A_price'].shift()` 
and then dividing between today's price and the new column price but the new columns results in mostly NaN's. 
Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### One liner

```
pd.concat([df, df.groupby('ID')[['A_price', 'B_price']].apply(lambda df: np.exp(np.log(df).diff()))], axis=1)
```

#### More reasonable

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def ratio(df):
    return np.exp(np.log(df).diff()) - 1

price_cols = ['A_price', 'B_price']
keys = ['Original', 'PctChange']
pd.concat([df, df.groupby('ID')[price_cols].apply(ratio)],
          axis=1, keys=keys)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution, using [pct_change()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) function:

```
In [484]: df[['A_price_ratio_increase','B_price_ratio_increase']] = \
              df.groupby('ID')['A_price','B_price'].pct_change()

In [485]: df
Out[485]:
   ID       Date  A_price  B_price  A_price_ratio_increase  B_price_ratio_increase
0   3 2013-01-01        2        5                     NaN                     NaN
1   3 2013-02-01        3        6                    0.50                     0.2
2   1 2013-01-01        2        4                     NaN                     NaN
3   1 2013-02-01        5        2                    1.50                    -0.5
4   1 2013-03-01        4        4                   -0.20                     1.0
5   1 2013-04-01        8       10                    1.00                     1.5
6   1 2013-05-01        8        2                    0.00                    -0.8
7   1 2013-06-01        2        5                   -0.75                     1.5
8   1 2013-01-01        3        6                    0.50                     0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

### First way

- First copy the original dataframe

  ```
  copied_df=df.copy()
  ```
- shift the df values 1 step forward

  ```
   copied_df.shift(periods=1)
  ```

this will shift all the columns 1 step forward. In your df, you should make sure that the date is set as the index column.

```
 copied_df.set_index("Date")
```

- create a new column "priceA_lag" that will shift the price of A i step forward.

  ```
  copied_df["priceA_lag"]=copied_df.A_price.shift(periods=1)
  ```
- Create another column "PriceA_diff"

  ```
  copied_df["PriceA_diff"]=copied_df.A_price.sub(copied_df.priceA_lag)
  ```

### Second way

```
df["A_price_dif"]=df.A_price.diff(periods=1)
```